# Fixme List with Chapter names

Tags: table-of-contents, packages

I am using the FixMe-package documented [here](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~didier/software/fixme.pdf).

In the beginning of my document, I print a list of fixme's with \listoffixmes, but this list is rather tedious to read. Is it possible to break this list up by my chapters, such that I can easily see the fixme's of each section in a separate list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define

```
\newcommand{\listoffixmebreak}{%
  \addtocontents{lox}{\protect\vspace{\bigskipamount}}}
```

Using `\listoffixmebreak` before a chapter title (after the first) will add a vertical space between entries referring to a chapter.

If you need to have a reference to the chapter, you can say

```
\newcommand{\listoffixmechapter}{%
  \addtocontents{lox}{\protect\vspace{\bigskipamount}\noindent
    Chapter \thechapter\ notes}}
```

and use `\listoffixmechapter` after a `\chapter` command. Personalize at will.

This might be added to the definition of `\chapter`, but I don't think it's really a problem.